# C++ Global namespace variable not being initialized - always

Tags: c++, static, initialization, global-variables

There are a bunch of strings declared in a namespace. i.e.

```
const std::string string1 = "string1";
```

Main calls a function which uses one of these strings however the string is always empty. i.e. this fails

```
assert(!string1.empty());
```

I am aware of the static initialization fiasco however this behavior is happening after main is called, everything should be initialized by this point right? Additionally this happens without fail no matter how many times I run or make clean && make.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem or get a better handle on what is wrong?

Edit:
My apologies, I was wrong when I said that this was happening after main was called. I had declared my own namespace variable which was trying to access the other, uninitialized ones I mentioned, in its constructor.

I took yzt's advice and wrapped my own namespace variable in a function so that it would be initialized when it was first used.

Comment: Can you give a small compilable example that exposes the error?

Comment: This is a part of a big messy framework. I'm not sure if I will be able to recreate the problem but I'll try.

Comment: You are sure there is no local string1 hiding the global?

Comment: I've checked and it has only been defined once.

Comment: perhaps those strings are in a dynamic library.

Comment: Check what happens if you make your own class and make a global variable. Write something to output in the constructor and see if all the global variables are not initialized or is it specific to the std::string.

Comment: Try renaming `string1` to something more unique (e.g. `string12345`) and see if it fails too

Comment: @user2675345: You can initialize the variable using a function that returns a `string` (instead of directly with a literal) and then put a breakpoint in that function to see whether/when it is called. Obviously, this function can be a simple pass-through function that just returns its argument.

Comment: Different namespaces (header vs source) ?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.

@yzt your advice helped me the most, thank you.